# How to replace for..loop on large data (about million of rows) by another way in qlik sense

Tags: foreach, bigdata, database-performance, large-data, qliksense

I have a large data about million rows.
I have to generate the field which need to loop all rows in my data table.
This loop makes the performance lowly and nonexecutive.

So is there any way or solution for this, especially on Qlik Sense?

The sample structure look like as below:

```
FOR Each a in FieldValueList('employee')  ~~~~ about 1 million rows


  For i = 1 to $(vdate)                    ~~~~ about 3 month, equivalent 90 days


find max and append to a table....


Next i


Next a;
```

Thank you

Comment: is there any specific reason why you are implementing loop? I think that the same can be achieved using `max` and `group by` from the source table

Answer (score 0):

A faster way to do this should be:

- create a table of the date range using a for loop (should only be 90 loops (for 90 days) so very quick)
- load in employee field
- use JOIN to link the date table to the table holding the employee field.

The join expression would be something like:

```
// do everything else before here
join (Employees) // assumes table called employees
load * resident [Employee dates]  // assumes table holding dates called Employee dates

// clean up
drop table [Employee dates];
```

Hope this helps.

Rod